# Preferred Boolean type for ABAP Development

Tags: abap

SAP doesn't have a core Data Type for boolean values. Additionally, higher level boolean types in SAP typically have three states: true ('X'), false (' ') and unknown ('-').

Now obviously booleans are a cornerstone of a lot of my development work but I realised that I haven't been terribly consistent in my type (data element) usage. So far I believe these are the most common:

- `abap_bool`: defined in the abap type-pool, unconstrained but constants are defined for true, false, unknown, yes and no
- `os_boolean`: data element, Yes ('X') or No (' ')
- `xfeld`: data element, True ('X') or False (' '), lacks a field label, described as a checkbox

In my code I've mainly used `abap_bool` as I can then work with constants instead of character values, not that I couldn't assign `abap_true` to an `xfeld`. However, I've been cautioned that this type pool might not always be available.

I'm now wondering about the best practices for boolean values, specifically:

- Is there a preferred type that I should use?
- Will using the abap type-pool cause issues in certain modules or scenarios?
- Does the possibility of abap_bool containing an unknown or indeed any character value matter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use the type pool `ABAP` and its constants in coding. It should always be available, though you may have to include it manually on older systems. For dictionary elements, I prefer to create my own data elements using any of the default domains so that I can add descriptions to suit my needs. You can use WDY_BOOLEAN as well.

Comment: The one place where this type can't be used is in Web Dynpro parameter definitions since the "Use of type pools is not supported in Web Dynpro".

Comment: @Lilienthal - `WDY_BOOLEAN` can be used in WebDynpro applications.

Comment: @mjturner `WDY_BOOLEAN` only supports binary values, not abap_undefined, but then so do `XFELD` and `OS_BOOLEAN`.

Comment: @Lilienthal Indeed, that's true. Must confess, I'm not at all a fan of abap_undefined (and don't recall ever having to use it in anger!).

Comment: @mjturner I definitely agree and can only recall a single time I used it as a tri-state return value. The assumption that booleans only have two possible states seems like a fairly safe one when developing in ABAP.

Comment: @mjturner @Lilienthal The tri-state is VERY useful for optional parameters. There is no easy way to check optional parameters properly... `IS SUPPLIED` and `IS INITIAL` are both inadequate when you do recursive calling or call internal worker methods.

Answer (score 10):

According to rule 6.11 of the [Official ABAP Programming Guidelines](http://www.sap-press.com/products/Official-ABAP-Programming-Guidelines.html), you should use abap_bool.

> Rule 6.11: Use the abap_bool Data Type for Truth Values
>
> To explicitly
> handle truth values, use the abap_bool type as a workaround for a real
> Boolean data type. A data object that is declared in this way is not
> supposed to contain other values than the corresponding constants,
> abap_true and abap_false (as well as abap_undefined).

Comment: you are also able to use WDY_BOOLEAN in Webdynpro Context, or BOOL_D in regular context as data element. You can also use FLAG, there are several ways, all doing the same ;) Even CHAR1 would solve the bool :D

Answer (score 4):

Update for [Release 7.40, SP08](http://scn.sap.com/community/abap/blog/2014/09/29/abap-news-for-740-sp08--logical-expressions):

With Release 7.40, SP08 you get the *Predicative Method Calls* and you can code something like:

```
IF cl_abap_demo_services=>is_production_system( ).  "There is no '= abap_true' needed!
    cl_demo_output=>display(
       'This demo cannot be executed in a production system' ).
    LEAVE PROGRAM.
ENDIF.
```

Your method (in the example `is_production_system`) must return a [ABAP_BOOL-value](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_731/en/abendataobjects_true_value_guidl.htm) (abap_true ('X') or abap_false (' '))

The [online help](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm?file=ABENpredicative_method_call_abexa.htm) has an example.

Comment: Very interesting. But if I read [the docu](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/index.htm?file=ABENpredicative_method_call_abexa.htm) correctly, any non-initial value for the returning parameter will be considered as evaluating to true. As you say, use of `abap_true` and `abap_false` will work for this though.

Answer (score -2):

Sadly, this is the bane of ABAP... not having a fundamental boolean type... only boolean expressions. So the wonderful thing in ABAP is that there are so many boolean types to choose from!

After many years I believe the *best* way is to just roll your own (sadly). If you do class-based development, then always just add a `true` and `false` (and `undefined` if you wish) constants in your base class, and define your own boolean and/or boolean_undefined types.

Comment: Hmm, why would you define your own over using the `abap_...` constants provided in the ABAP type pool? I'm not sure the shorter and for new devs more obvious true/false weighs up to the extra maintenance effort and clutter.

Comment: @Lilienthal , although type-pools will work, the problem is if you develop multi-release software. On certain older systems they are pretty sensitive as to where you include your type pools. Also, we prefer to just re-declare all our own types (even if a suitable one exists on the system) because it's more stable in case SAP decides to remove/change some in the future. Having your own type also means you can refactor easier when you alter your basic types. (Adding/altering `undefined` or `initial` as a bool type for instance?)